# Finding out an optional consumption without calculation

Tags: microeconomics, utility

I need help with this task.

The utility function is *U(a;b)=3a+2b.* 
The prices for the goods *a* and *b* are equal. 
Explain what an optional consumption of the consumer would be without calculating.

How do I explain it without math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the prices of **a** and **b** are equal, but the consumer gets more utility from **a** (**3a** vs. **2b**) then the optimal consumption would be to purchase as much of **a** as possible, and only purchase **b** if **a** has run out.

I'd also like to point out it doesn't completely make sense to explain a math equation without math...

Comment: [Should I](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/should-i-downvote-valid-answers-to-off-topic-questions)?

Comment: @denesp I'd like to point out stackoverflow is full of highly upvoted answers to off-topic questions fwiw.

Comment: Thank you! So I just need to look at the coefficients, right? 
Can the graph help me as well? 
I know it makes no sense without calculating what that is what the task is.

Comment: @serakfalcon Stackoverflow is free to decide on its own policy, as is any SE site.